# PHP str_replace cambiar url completa

Tags: php, url, str-replace

Estoy tratando de imprimir una página pero antes necesito modificar algunas urls usando la expresion `str_replace`. Tengo urls de tipo:

```
https://dominioaremplzar.com/#!RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==
```

He intentado de la formas mas corta

```
$dominio="https://dominioaremplzar.com";

$html= str_replace($domiminio, "minuevodominio.com", $html);
```

con esto solo logro remplzar el dominio quedando asi:

```
minuevodominio.com/#!RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==
```

Necesito eliminar los caracteres que faltan, en este caso:

```
#!RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==
```

En teoría necesito remplazar toda la url por mi url nueva, no estoy seguro si debo usar `preg_match_all` para un mejor resultado.

Soy nuevo en esto de porgramación web, espero me puedan dar una ayudita saludos.

Comment: No se entiende lo que tratas de hacer con la url porque al cambiarla esta pierde su ruta, ahora bien si lo que deseas es recortar su contenido trata con un shorter url como: https://bitly.com/  otra cosa que puedes intentar es configurar el .HTACCESS

Comment: lo que necesito es remplazar la url completa, pero solo logro cambiar el dominio

Comment: En ese caso no necesitas usar str_replace() mas bien asignale un nuevo valor al string de esta forma: $html="https://dominioaremplzar.com"; directamente

Comment: tengo la url https://dominioaremplzar.com/#!RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==  la cual necesito cambiar por la ulr nueva

Comment: No se entiende qué es lo que quieres. Por favor, pon un ejemplo del resultado final que quieres obtener. Tu explicación es confusa. Gracias.

Comment: La respuesta dependerá un poco de lo que haya dentro de la variable `$html`. Esta variable únicamente tiene el enlace? O por el contrario tiene más texto html además de el enlace. Además: Los enlaces que quieres remplazar siempre tienen el formato de la pregunta? Sin saber esto no es posible dar una respuesta que se ajuste a lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Existe una funcion en php llamada parse_url(), la cual le envías el parámetro de la url, y te la devuelve en un array con los componentes que la conforman.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://dominioaremplzar.com/#!RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==';
$partes_url = parse_url($url);
print_r($partes_url);
?>
```

esto te devuelve el array con los componentes de la url:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => dominioaremplzar.com
    [path] => /
    [fragment] => !RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==
)
```

Ya sería cuestión que concatenes los elementos que quieres cambiar, por los nuevos elementos, ejemplo:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://dominioaremplzar.com/#!RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==';
$partes_url = parse_url($url);
print_r($partes_url);

$nuevo_host = 'hckdrk.mx';
$nuevo_fragment = '#!Aqui_el_nuevo_fragment';

$nueva_url = $partes_url['scheme'] . '://' . $nuevo_host . $partes_url['path'] . $nuevo_fragment;

$partes_nueva_url = parse_url($nueva_url);
print_r($partes_nueva_url);


?>
```

Y así quedaría:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => dominioaremplzar.com
    [path] => /
    [fragment] => !RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==
)
Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => hckdrk.mx
    [path] => /
    [fragment] => !Aqui_el_nuevo_fragment
)
```

Puedes revisar la documentación completa en la página oficial de php: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos cosas que puedes hacer analizando tu pregunta:

1) Si la variable $html es con la que recibes el URL y esta la puedes cambiar su contenido mediante str_replace() entonces lo que sugiero es que le asignes de una vez a esa variable el valor del nuevo url:
EJ:
$html="minuevodominio.com";

2) Si desea cambiar el contenido despues de aplicar el `str_replace()` aplica el siguiente codigo donde usando `substr()` sustraes la cadena de caracteres desea y descartas lo demas:

```
$html = 'https://dominioaremplzar.com/#!RTVBYkFxN2lqUWFHQjhCRHJLOUVCQWhEb1hFYzFPRjVoZmFCY0JYTlFGOGhkeWxBY0I2UTlCWHlTQms1YThjWA==';
$dominio="https://dominioaremplzar.com";

$html= str_replace($dominio, "minuevodominio.com", $html);
$html= substr($html, 0,strlen("minuevodominio.com"));
```

La salida quedaria asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]